# Test automation script with ruby, watir-webdriver to run in Safari browser in Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, watir-webdriver, safari

I found in different places that, automation with safari can be done in MAC OS as safari is also an Apple product. But, we can download and install safari browser in windows and test there manually.

Is there any way or at least way around to write test automation script with ruby, watir-webdriver to run in Safari browser in Windows OS?

For example, I just want to open safari browser like other browsers (firefox, chrome, ie) in windows and rest part of the scripts are supposed to run same in all browsers.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

The highest version of Safari for Windows is too old. It's also not able to handle many modern web technologies, so you're better off using either a containerized version of Safari, or sticking to Mac OS to test Safari.